# nHibernate synchronize two databases

Tags: c#, database, nhibernate, synchronize

I have two databases with the same structure on different servers and have to synchronize them bidirectionally. In databese 1 need to send sales information in database 2 need to send information from entries. I need to make this sync with nhibernate because the system can be used with any database: postgreSQL, mysql, oracle, sqlserver, etc..

What is the best strategy to make this application?

Comment: did you try something already? Any strategy you have in mind so far? SO is not the place where you get a ready solution ;)

Synchronizing 2 databases can be a pretty nasty task even if you don't have different db systems... I would try to prevent this from happening at all cost.

Comment: im looking for sugetions.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to figure out a couple of things:

1. Spin up session factories for the two databases you need to sync
2. Identify objects that need to be synchronized
3. Sync them with the merge command

`ISession.Merge()`

> - if there is a persistent instance with the same identifier currently
>      associated with the session, copy the state of the given object onto
>      the persistent instance
> - if there is no persistent instance currently associated with the
>      session, try to load it from the database, or create a new persistent
>      instance
> - the persistent instance is returned
> - the given instance does not become associated with the session, it
>      remains detached

We actually do something similar when we archive data between databases.  The trickiest part for you may be identifying what needs to by synced.

Comment: Do you use some design pattern to do it?

Comment: @Bruno To do which part?

Comment: Whats the diference between Merge and Replicate

Comment: @Bruno I'm not sure what you mean by Replicate.  There is no method in ISession called Replicate that I'm aware of.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2010/05/18/lesser-known-nhibernate-session-methods.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is to be honest I'd have to probably test it.  We use merge to do what you are describing and it works.